# How to optimize this R script performance

Tags: r

I want to optimize my code (shown below) which is really slow (especially in the looping stage). I have a sample data `mydata` (the actual matrix is of 666,669 X 4345 size). What this code does is it looks for the letter in REF and ALT columns in `mymat` where they could have any of A,T,G,C letters (only one letter). In the columns ending with .GT, replaces these letters with the condition: if there is 0, replaces it with the letter in REF column and if there is 1 replaces it with the letter in ALT column. If there is NA, it then replaces it with "0" "0" (i.e., zero space zero). Finally, it inverts all the .GT columns across the rows (transpose) as shown in the result. In the result, everything is separated by space. Is there a way to optimize this code?
code:

```
    all.samples<-c("02688","02689")
    letters <- strsplit(paste(mymat[,"REF"],mymat[,"ALT"],sep=","),",") # concatenate the letters to have an index to work on from the numbers
    values <- t(mymat[,c(which(colnames(mymat)%in%lapply(all.samples,function(x)(paste(x,"GT",sep=".")))))]) # working on each column needing values
    nbval <- ncol(values) # Keeping track of total number of columns and saving the length of values 

    #Preparing the two temp vectors to be used below
    chars <- vector("character",2) 
    ret <- vector("character",nbval)

    #This is where everything becomes slow; Loop over the rows (and transpose the result)
    mydata<-t(sapply(rownames(values),
                     function(x) { 
                       indexes <- strsplit(values[x,],"/") # Get a list with pairs of indexes

                       for(i in 1:nbval) { # Loop over the number of columns :/
                         for (j in 1:2) { # Loop over the pair 
                           chars[j] <- ifelse(indexes[i] == "NA", 0,letters[[i]][as.integer(indexes[[i]][j])+1]) # Get '0' if "NA" or the letter with the correct index at this postion
                         }
                         ret[i] <- paste(chars[1],chars[2], sep=" ") # concatenate the two chars
                       }
                       return(ret) # return this for this row
                     }
    ))
```

Sample data:

```
mymat<-structure(c("G", "A", "C", "A", "G", "A", "C", "T", "G", "A", 
"1/1", "0/0", "0/0", "NA", "NA", "0,15", "8,0", "8,0", "NA", 
"NA", "1/1", "0/1", "0/0", "NA", "NA", "0,35", "12,12", "15,0", 
"NA", "NA"), .Dim = 5:6, .Dimnames = list(c("chrX:133511988:133511988:G:A:snp", 
"chrX:133528116:133528116:A:C:snp", "chrX:133528186:133528186:C:T:snp", 
"chrX:133560301:133560301:A:G:snp", "chrX:133561242:133561242:G:A:snp"
), c("REF", "ALT", "02688.GT", "02688.AD", "02689.GT", "02689.AD"
)))
```

result

```
    >mydata
    02688.GT  A A A A C C 0 0 0 0
    02689.GT  A A A C C C 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: The problem is your test data won't reproduce the slowness.  It would also help if you profile your code to give us hints where optimization would have an effect.

Comment: @bdecaf Basically the looping stage is really slow. I wanted to replace the loops with apply function. I tried using dplyr, but converting matrix to dataframe generates another issue. This snippet of code is within a loop that uses various other functions in prior steps. I need something to replace this loop part that would possibly optimize the process.